# Does the OST come with only the Humble Bundle version of the game?

Tags: steam, humble-bundle, costume-quest

I just bought Costume Quest on Humble Bundle and got the OST with it, but its existence wasn't even mentioned on the [store page](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/costume-quest).

Installing my Steam version reveals no OST in the game files... And I know there's an [itch.io](https://doublefine.itch.io/costume-quest) version.

Is the OST a Humble Bundle exclusive, other than buying it from the Double Fine [Bandcamp](https://doublefine.bandcamp.com/album/costume-quest-original-soundtrack) separately?

Comment: Steam DB has a record for it: https://steamdb.info/app/115107/info/ but yea - I am not finding it on Steam or anywhere else.  I wonder if you were to buy the game on Steam if you just get the sound track also despite no mention of it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You can download the OST from your Humble Library just like the DRM free version of the game. You could also bought on other platforms (e.g. Bandcamp or Apple Music) so it is not exclusive. It is just not available on Steam.

Comment: @Tim - I'm asking if the only version of the game that comes with the OST, is the Humble Bundle version.